# SQL add IDENTITY base on grouped column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have data like this:

```
FirstName     LastName
El            Even
Mike          Wheeler
Mike          Byers
Dustin        Henderson
```

And my desired output is to add Identity into each of the unique FirstName

```
ID   FirstName     LastName
1    El            Even
2    Mike          Wheeler
2    Mike          Byers
3    Dustin        Henderson
```

The way I do this is:

```
/* part 1 */
SELECT IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS ID, FirstName 
INTO TabTemp FROM TabName 
GROUP BY FirstName

/* part 2 */
SELECT B.ID, A.FirstName, A.LastName 
INTO TabTempFinal FROM TabName A, TabTemp B
WHERE A.FistName = B.FirstName
```

My question is can I achieve the result without using the part 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.  You can't add an `identity` column to a table where the identity is not supposed to be unique.  That is not how `identity` columns work.

But, you can use `dense_rank()` instead:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName) AS ID,
       FirstName, LastName
INTO TabTempFinal
FROM TabName ;
```

This generates the unique indicator for each `FirstName`.  The only difference is that the column is not an `identity` column.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the `dense_rank` window function:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY first_name) AS id,
       first_name,
       last_name
FROM   tabname
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen dang. I have no idea where that E came from. I guess [nothing good ever happens after 2AM](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiGk6ravfTXAhXD6aQKHZAmBvIQtwIIMzAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D6bGMs3Kpt_8&usg=AOvVaw2qbp2TwZvMbHLbEjQOn8g0).

Comment: Yeah...I know you are in Israel and did find it odd to see you online when I was heading to work here in Asia +1.

Answer (score 1):

You could do an update with a CTE using `DENSE_RANK`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName) dr
    FROM TabName
)

UPDATE cte
SET ID = dr;
```

This assumes that you already have a column called `ID`.